# Pinescript Version 5 - Fibonacci Retracement Indicator Syntax error at input

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am trying to implement a pinescript version 5 fibonacci retracement indicator into my trading strategy but I keep getting the following error: <Syntax error at input '='> but when I change it to <Syntax error at input ':='> it wants me to change back to <"=">.

I have tried changing the formating of the code several different times and adding in () in different areas but I still seem to get the same error when trying to store an array float.

Full code below

```
//@version=5
strategy("Supetrend, MACD and RSI Strategy", overlay=true, default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, default_qty_value=110,
     initial_capital=100, margin_long=0.1, margin_short=0.1)

// Define Fibonacci Retracement : Inputs
entry_size = input.float(100, title="Entry Size (in USD)")
stop_loss = input.float(50, title="Stop Loss (in USD)")
take_profit = input.float(200, title="Take Profit (in USD)")
fib_levels = input.string(title="Fibonacci Levels", defval="0.236,0.382,0.5,0.618,0.786")
fib_breakout_range = input.int(10, title="Fibonacci Breakout Range")

// Calculate Fibonacci Retracement
// split the string into an array of substrings using the "," delimiter
var fib_levels_arr = str.split(fib_levels, ",")

// create a new float array with the same size as fib_levels_arr
var fib_levels_arr_f = array.new_float(fib_levels_arr.size())

// iterate over each index of fib_levels_arr, convert the string to a float and store it in the corresponding index of fib_levels_arr_f
for i = 0 to fib_levels_arr.size() - 1
    fib_levels_arr_f[i] := float(fib_levels_arr[i])

fib_swing_high = ta.highest(high, 5)
fib_swing_low = ta.lowest(low, 5)
fib_price_range = fib_swing_high - fib_swing_low

fib_levels_prices = array.new_float(fib_levels_arr.size(), na)

for i = 0 to int(fib_levels_arr.size() - 1)
    fib_levels_prices([i]) := fib_swing_high - fib_levels_arr_f[i] * fib_price_range

fib_breakout_level = ta.pivothigh(high, fib_breakout_range, fib_breakout_range)
fib_support_level = ta.pivotlow(low, fib_breakout_range, fib_breakout_range)
```

The error is located in this section of code:

```
for i = 0 to fib_levels_arr.size() - 1
    fib_levels_arr_f[i] := float(fib_levels_arr[i])
```

and also here as its probably the same issue:

```
for i = 0 to int(fib_levels_arr.size() - 1)
    fib_levels_prices([i]) := fib_swing_high - fib_levels_arr_f[i] * fib_price_range
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To access an array's element, you should use `array.get()`.

To set the value of an array's element, you should use `array.set()`.

You should write this expression:

```
for i = 0 to fib_levels_arr.size() - 1
    fib_levels_arr_f[i] := float(fib_levels_arr[i])
```

as

```
for i = 0 to array.size(fib_levels_arr) - 1
    array.set(fib_levels_arr_f, i, array.get(fib_levels_arr, i))
```